# PHP SESSION cookie not set for some users

Tags: php, session, cookies, nginx

I have two domains: domain.com (with old version of site) and new.domain.com (new version).
Old and new sites placed on different platforms (old on VDS, and new in cloud).
When I change IP for domain.com to new site there are problem with session on some users who browse domain.com (if they go on new.domain.com all good).

On one test computer there are session cookie, but on another there aren't. On both computers uses Chome.

How to check is there are problem with sripts or with server configuration?

On server uses Nginx as balancier and caching proxy, Apache as web-server.

========== added ==========

Session cookie saves when I check 'remember me' while login.
This option set extra cookie.

========== added ==========

I double check. Session cookie not save. It is only 'remember me' cookie.

Answer (score 0):

In headers I see that session cookie is sets with domain 'new.domain.com' - this is why cookie not sets for 'domain.com'.

I look into config files on server and in file **php.ini** there are option **session.cookie_domain** in **[Session]** section. This option was set to 'new.domain.com'